# Problems with time series prediction

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, compositional-data

I got a question about modeling time series in R.
my data consist of the following matrix:

```
1   0.03333333 0.01111111 0.9555556
2   0.03810624 0.02309469 0.9387991
3   0.00000000 0.03846154 0.9615385
4   0.03776683 0.03119869 0.9310345
5   0.06606607 0.01201201 0.9219219
6   0.03900325 0.02058505 0.9404117
7   0.03125000 0.01562500 0.9531250
8   0.00000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
9   0.04927885 0.01802885 0.9326923
10  0.06106870 0.02290076 0.9160305
11  0.03846154 0.00000000 0.9615385
12  0.00000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
13  0.06028636 0.03843256 0.9012811
14  0.09646302 0.05144695 0.8520900
15  0.04444444 0.06666667 0.8888889
```

these matrix has in total 200 rows.

as you can see in each situation the sum of each row is 1, that becomes because the values are the percentage of a whole. for example row 1 contains 3.33% of variable a, 1.11% of variable 2 and 95.5% of veriable 3.
the first collomn indicates the year that the values are measured.

my target is to make a prediction for the next 5 years, so from year 200 to 205.

I can doe that by making three normal time series forecast. But for that forecast the total sum is never equal to 1, which is very important. 
Normaly is use techniques like arima and exponential smoothing.

Does somebody know a method to make a forecast for such a problem?

Comment: Do you know if these are discrete proportions (eg, number of units in categories A, B, & C, given a total number of units) or continuous proportions? If they are discrete, do you know the total number of units at each time point?

Comment: Yes these values comes from discrete units, I calculated these ratios with use of the total numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are attempting to forecast a *compositional* time series. That is, you have three components that are all constrained to lie between 0 and 1 and to add up to 1.

You can address this issue using standard exponential smoothing, by using an appropriate generalized logistic transformation. There was [a presentation on this by Koehler, Snyder, Ord & Beaumont](http://forecasters.org/submissions10/KoehlerAneISF2010.pdf) at the 2010 [International Symposium on Forecasting](http://forecasters.org/isf/), which turned into a paper ([Snyder et al., 2017, *International Journal of Forecasting*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2016.11.008)).

Let's walk though this with your data. Read the data into a matrix `obs` of time series:

```
obs <- structure(c(0.03333333, 0.03810624, 0, 0.03776683, 0.06606607, 
0.03900325, 0.03125, 0, 0.04927885, 0.0610687, 0.03846154, 0, 
0.06028636, 0.09646302, 0.04444444, 0.01111111, 0.02309469, 0.03846154, 
0.03119869, 0.01201201, 0.02058505, 0.015625, 0, 0.01802885, 
0.02290076, 0, 0, 0.03843256, 0.05144695, 0.06666667, 0.9555556, 
0.9387991, 0.9615385, 0.9310345, 0.9219219, 0.9404117, 0.953125, 
1, 0.9326923, 0.9160305, 0.9615385, 1, 0.9012811, 0.85209, 0.8888889
), .Dim = c(15L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Series 1", "Series 2", 
"Series 3")), .Tsp = c(1, 15, 1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"
))
```

You can check whether this worked by typing

```
obs
```

Now, you have a few zeros in there, which will be a problem once you take logarithms. A simple solution is to set everything that is less than a small $\epsilon$ to that $\epsilon$:

```
epsilon <- 0.0001
obs[obs<epsilon] <- epsilon
```

Now the modified rows do not sum to 1 any more. We can rectify that (although I think this might make the forecast worse):

```
obs <- obs/matrix(rowSums(obs),nrow=nrow(obs),ncol=ncol(obs),byrow=FALSE)
```

Now we transform the data as per page 35 of the presentation:

```
zz <- log(obs[,-ncol(obs)]/obs[,ncol(obs)])
colnames(zz) <- head(colnames(obs),-1)
zz
```

Load the `forecast` package and set a horizon of 5 time points:

```
library(forecast)
horizon <- 5
```

Now model and forecast the transformed data column by column. Here I am simply calling `ets()`, which will attempt to fit a state space exponential smoothing model. It turns out that it uses single exponential smoothing for all three series, but especially if you have more than 15 time periods, it may select trend models. Or if you have monthly data, explain to R that you have a potential seasonality, by using `ts()` with `frequency=12` - then `ets()` will look at seasonal models.

```
baz <- apply(zz,2,function(xx)forecast(ets(xx),horizon=horizon)["mean"])
forecasts.transformed <- cbind(baz[[1]]$mean,baz[[2]]$mean)
```

Next we backtransform the forecasts as per page 38 of the presentation:

```
forecasts <- cbind(exp(forecasts.transformed),1)/(1+rowSums(exp(forecasts.transformed)))
```

Finally, let's plot histories and forecasts:

```
plot(obs[,1],ylim=c(0,1),xlim=c(1,nrow(obs)+horizon),type="n",ylab="")
for ( ii in 1:ncol(obs) ) {
    lines(obs[,ii],type="o",pch=19,col=ii)
    lines(forecasts[,ii],type="o",pch=21,col=ii,lty=2)
}
legend("left",inset=.01,lwd=1,col=1:ncol(obs),pch=19,legend=colnames(obs))
```

[image: compositional forecasts]

EDIT: [a paper on compositional time series forecasting](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/for.2336/abstract) just appeared. I haven't read it, but it may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks @stephan Kolassa, that is exactly what I mean. Does anybody knows wether there is toolpack in R to make a forecasting with compositional time series.

Comment: I don't think so, and these authors are not among the "always write a companion R package to any publication" people. But their approach is pretty simple and should not require more than five lines to preprocess your time series, after which you can use the standard tools (e.g., `ets()` in the `forecast` package for state space exponential smoothing).

Comment: My mathematical knowledge is not that good. can you maybe help with the pre processing the data? when the data is in the right format i can do the forecasting process.

Comment: I was wandering if you have found some time to help me with the problem I had with the compositional time series?

Comment: Here you go. Sorry it took a while; I actually got stuck understanding the presentation and had to clear my head.

Comment: There are essentially two variables to model since the three variables should sum to one.

Comment: @xeon: indeed. In the code above, `zz` is a matrix with two transformed columns, corresponding to the first two columns of the original three ones. The problem in "simply" forecasting these is twofold: (a) the "simple" forecast of one of these columns could be <0, and (b) the sum of the "simple" forecasts of these two could be >1 (so the third component would by <0).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks a lot for al the good help:D

Comment: @karmabob: I just edited the answer to link to a paper on compositional time series forecasting that just appeared - may be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The method mentioned by Stephan Kolassa is called Additive Log-Ratio Transformation (alr). For an overview of compositional data analysis, see my answer to [R - multinomial logistic regression with relative frequencies as response variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/638102). There are a few other transformation, such as Centered Log-Ratio Transformation (clr) and Isometric Log-Ratio Transformation (ilr). Since your objective is to forecast time series, common methods for cross-sectional compositional data, such as fractional multinomial logit models and Dirichlet regression, may not be a good choice.

Since your proportions come from integer values with their total known, you can conduct hierarchical forecast of the raw values by allocating a total to three components, which is also featured in the `forecast` package, instead of the derived proportions. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/hierarchical.html. From the forecast raw values, you can derive forecast proportions.